# Maya MEL variables declaration and initialization

Tags: variables, maya, mel

Is it obligatory in MEL to initialize variables and especially strings when you declare them?

I know that it is not necessary to initialize string arrays:

```
string $buffer[];
$buffer[0] = "abc";
```

But what about strings and other variable types? Is it acceptably:

```
string $str;
$str = "abc";
```

Or should always use double quotes to initialize it?

```
string $str = "";
$str = "abc";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to populate the variable, initializing it with a type declaration sets it to a default value  (0 for ints, 0.0 for floats, and "" for strings).  In general it's good practice to assign in place when the initial variable is meaningful:

```
string $topCamera  = "|top|topShape";
```

but it's fine to declare an empty variable when you need to placeholder but don't have the value yet;

```
int $cameraCount;
// make some cameras here;
$cameraCount = size(`ls -type camera`);
```

It doesn't hurt to declare $cameraCount as 0 in that example but it's just extra typing.

**Insert obligatory warning to learn python instead here**

Answer (score 0):

> As a general rule, it is best to explicitly declare the type of a variable when it is defined. This ensures that you aren't depending on
>   Maya to automatically determine the variable type for you.

from 
[Complete Maya Programming 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001UN2WBG)

use `string $str;`